# How can I reset a JavaFX node to its default position before transformations

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a JavaFX application that shows a nature scene including a Tree object that is made up of several shapes. After constructing the tree I store it in a Group which is added to a pane. I need to use radio buttons to rotate the tree by 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees.

My problem is that my implementation of the rotation buttons sets them relatively from where the trees' current angle, instead of absolutely. I believe I can fix this by resetting the rotation to its default when a button is selected before applying the new rotation, but I can't find a method to this. Thank you!

Adding the tree to the Pane:

```
Tree t1 = new Tree(100, 400);
tree = new Group();
tree.getChildren().addAll(t1.getAllNodes());
scenery.getChildren().add(tree);
```

The beginning of my radio button handler class:

```
private class radioButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Rotate treeRotation = new Rotate();
            treeRotation.setPivotX(100);
            treeRotation.setPivotY(300);

            if (e.getSource() == ninetyDegrees) {
                treeRotation.setAngle(90);
                tree.getTransforms().add(treeRotation);
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == oneEightyDegrees) {
                treeRotation.setAngle(180);
                tree.getTransforms().add(treeRotation);
            }
```

Creating the radio buttons:

```
 //radio buttons:
        radioButtonHandler radiobuttonHandler = new radioButtonHandler();
        rotationGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        zeroDegrees = new RadioButton("0 Degrees");
        zeroDegrees.setToggleGroup(rotationGroup);
        ninetyDegrees = new RadioButton("90 Degrees");
        ninetyDegrees.setOnAction(radiobuttonHandler);
        ninetyDegrees.setToggleGroup(rotationGroup);
        oneEightyDegrees = new RadioButton("180 Degrees");
        oneEightyDegrees.setOnAction(radiobuttonHandler);
        oneEightyDegrees.setToggleGroup(rotationGroup);
        twoSeventyDegrees = new RadioButton("270 Degrees");
        twoSeventyDegrees.setOnAction(radiobuttonHandler);
        twoSeventyDegrees.setToggleGroup(rotationGroup);
        rotationGroup.selectToggle(zeroDegrees);
```

If I select the 90 Degrees button first, and then subsequently select the 180 Degrees button the tree will wind up in the same position as if I had selected the 270 Degrees button at the beginning.

Comment: Try reusing the same `Rotate` object instead of creating a new one and appending it to the transformations list every time. Or, if this one rotation is the only transformation, clear the list before adding the new `Rotate`.

Comment: @Slaw thank you so much!! `.getTransforms().clear()` wound up being exactly what i was looking for.